# Json query only returns first 2000 results - how do I get the rest?

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to query the Legiscan API and pull down all bills that have "passed" state legislatures
My current query: `https://api.legiscan.com/?key=APIKEY&op=searchRaw&state=ALL&query=status:passed`

Returns only the first `2000` results out of `24409`. I've looked [through the documentation](https://legiscan.com/gaits/documentation/legiscan) and I've tried modifying the `status:passed` part with different variations of the query from the summary part of the json file that gets returned:

```
{'status': 'OK', 'searchresult': {'summary': {'page': '1 of 13', 'range': '1 - 2000', 'relevancy':
'100% - 100%', 'count': 24409, 'page_current': 1, 'page_total': 13, 'query': '(XSTATUS4:(pos=1))'}
```

I've tried:

`https://api.legiscan.com/?key=APIKEY&op=searchRaw&state=ALL&query=status:passed&pos:2`

And:

`https://api.legiscan.com/?key=APIKEY&op=searchRaw&state=ALL&query=status:passed&XSTATUS4:pos=2`

Both results return the same result. How can I get to the other results? I'm using Python and Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Most APIs have a limit on the number of results they return at once, and you have to keep calling it in a loop to get the rest.

Comment: Look at page 20 of the documentation regarding the `page` parameter.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`https://api.legiscan.com/?key=APIKEY&op=searchRaw&state=ALL&query=status:passed&page=2`

Needed to add the `page` paremeter.